# How do you specialise a templated function with a templated class?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, stdvector, specialization

So i have a templated function:

```
template<typename T>
int func(const T& input){
  //do stuff
}
```

And I'd like to specialise it with a templated class(like std::vector) So like this:

```
template<typename T>
int func(const std::vector<T>& input){
  //do specialised stuff
}
```

But I don't know how exactly you do it. Thanks!

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: It's an overload rather than a specialisation, but yeah, it should be fine. Give it a try!

Comment: You're right, it is an overload, but when I try to add the angular brackets after func, i.e func<std::vector<T>>, it gives me an error.

Comment: You cannot partially specialize function templates ... which is what the error message from the compiler should tell you. use a member function of a template structure instead

Comment: `<template T> struct S { static int func(const T& input); };` would allow specialization. And you can then replace `//do specialised stuff` by `return S::func(input); };`

Comment: @PersonGuy For a simple template like the one in the problem, you can skip the angular brackets and let it deduce the template arguments using the function arguments. BUT, if you want to be explicit, use `func<int>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply go on

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>  
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
int func(const vector<T>& a){
    for(auto i: a)         //do specialised stuff
        cout<< (i<<1) <<"\n";
    return 0;

}
int main() {

    vector<int> a={9,8,7};
    func(a);
}

18
16
14
```

multiple each array a by 2 (shift left once, << 1)